# Uploading an image file using Selenium

Tags: java, selenium, automation

I want to upload an image by clicking on the browse button, but an issue is there I cant handle the windows as Selenium didn't provide any access to it. So i am using the concept of Robot, but cant able to click the image which I wanted to select.

```
WebElement Account_logo = adriver.findElement(By.className("input-group-btn"));
Account_logo.click();
StringSelection ss = new StringSelection("//C:\\Users\\romit\\Desktop\\LOGO.jpgg");
Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard().setContents(ss, null);


Robot robot = new Robot();
robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_V);
robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_V);
robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
```

Comment: What is in error log ? I can see, that it could be a typo mistake in extension of file: LOGO.jpgg

Comment: did you try using sendKeys() to send path of the image to browse button ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
adriver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
StringSelection ss = new 
StringSelection("C:\\Users\\romit\\Desktop\\ELDEN\\LOGO.jpg");
Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard().setContents(ss, null);
Robot robot = new Robot();
robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
  Thread.sleep(2000);
robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_V);
  Thread.sleep(2000);
robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_V);
  Thread.sleep(2000);
robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
  Thread.sleep(2000);
robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
  Thread.sleep(2000);
robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
  Thread.sleep(2000);
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternative way (reliable for us) is to create AutoIt script, convert into exe file and use it like below:

## Java code:

```
// AutoIt script to set focus to file name field in browse window dialog
try {
    Runtime.getRuntime().exec(ConfigProperties.getBaseDirectory() + "\\conf\\windows\\autoit\\SetFocusToFileNameField.exe");
} catch (IOException e) {
    logger.info("Couldn't execute or set focus to file name field using AutoIt script: " + e.toString());
}
SleepUtil.sleepSmall();

// Imitate mouse events like ENTER, CTRL+C, CTRL+V
Robot robot;
try {
    robot = new Robot();
    robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
    robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_V);
    robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_V);
    robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
    SleepUtil.sleepMedium();

} catch (AWTException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

// AutoIt script to click to open button to attach file
try {
    Runtime.getRuntime().exec(ConfigProperties.getBaseDirectory() + "\\conf\\windows\\autoit\\ClickToOpenButton.exe");
    SleepUtil.sleepLongMedium();
} catch (IOException e) {
    logger.info("Couldn't click to open button to attach file using AutoIt script: " + e.toString());
}
```

## ClickToOpenButton.au3:

```
; Click to Open button in File Explorer dialog

ClickToOpenButton()

Func ClickToOpenButton()
   Local $windowHandle;
   Local $windowTitle;
   Local $openButton = "Button1";

   If WinExists("File Upload") Then
      $windowTitle = "File Upload";
   Else
      $windowTitle = "Open";
   EndIf

   $windowHandle = WinWait($windowTitle, "");
   If Not WinActive($windowHandle) Then WinActivate($windowHandle);
   ControlClick($windowHandle, "", $openButton);

   ; Local $openButtonHandle;
   ; Local $openButtonPosition;
   ; $openButtonHandle = ControlGetHandle($windowTitle, "", $openButton);
   ; $openButtonPosition = WinGetPos($openButtonHandle);
   ; MouseClick($MOUSE_CLICK_PRIMARY, $openButtonPosition[0]+20, $openButtonPosition[1]+10, 2);
EndFunc
```

## SetFocusToFileNameField.au3:

```
; Set focus to file name field in File Explorer dialog

SetFocusToFileNameField()

Func SetFocusToFileNameField()
   Local $windowHandle;
   Local $windowTitle;
   Local $windowField = "Edit1";

   If WinExists("File Upload") Then
      $windowTitle = "File Upload";
   Else
      $windowTitle = "Open";
   EndIf

   $windowHandle = WinWait($windowTitle, "");
   If Not WinActive($windowHandle) Then WinActivate($windowHandle);
   ControlSetText($windowHandle, "", "Edit1", "");
   ControlFocus($windowTitle, "", $windowField);
EndFunc
```